# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'project_issue_tracker' of null

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api

I write a code of issue tracker but I run into this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'project_issue_tracker' of
> null

This is my code: https://replit.com/@gros22/boilerplate-project-issuetracker-1#routes/api.js

```
const projectSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  project_name: String,
  project_issue_tracker: [issueSchema]
});
```

can someone help me?

Comment: I'm not seeing that line of code anywhere in the link you shared. Please add some more context or code from the lines in your api handler that are throwing the error.

Answer (score 0):

> Your query can return `null` value, you will need to handle that case.

In this situation `doc` variable is `null` and and your as trying to do `doc. project_issue_tracker`

Comment: Ok, and what can i do to fix this?

Thanks for the answer